# consulta postgresql con variables en codeigniter

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

tengo esta consulta:

```
$sql = " SELECT DISTINCT c.nombre_campo AS $column
    FROM $schema.campos_basicos AS cb
    INNER JOIN $schema.mapeo_campos_basicos AS mc ON mc.id_campos_basicos = cb.id_campos_basicos
    INNER JOIN $schema.campos AS c ON c.campo_id = mc.campo_id 
    WHERE cb.nombre_campo_destino = ?;"
```

que se ejecuta con: 
*$query = $this->db->query($sql, **[$column]**)*

no comprendo la función de las llaves **[ ]** en la construcción de la consulta, 
ya que al pasar el parámetro de **$column** es el mismo string en todo momento,

si alguien conociera una mejor forma de construir esta consulta

o me dijera que función tienen los **[]** en la consulta con codeigniter 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente la función `query()` de los [Query Bindings](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings) acepta 2 parámetros, un string con la consulta SQL a ejecutar y un array de valores a reemplazar en el query:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $array);
```

Ejemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = ? AND estatus = ? AND autor = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'ok', 'Jhon'));
```

Donde los valores del array deben de coincidir con la posición de los `?`  en el query.

###### "No comprendo la función de las llaves **[ ]** en la construcción de la consulta..."

[Según los detalles tecnicos de la función array:](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array.asp)

> A partir de PHP 5.4, es posible utilizar una sintaxis de arreglos corta, que reemplaza array() con [].
> P.ej. **$coches = ["Volvo", "BMW"];** en lugar de **$coches = array("Volvo", "BMW");**

```
$coches = ["Volvo", "BMW"]; //válido
$coches = array("Volvo", "BMW"); //válido

//Es válido utilizar ambas maneras:
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'ok', 'Jhon'));
$this->db->query($sql, [3, 'ok', 'Jhon']);
```

Finalmente y según la documentación de [Codeigniter 4](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings):

> *The secondary benefit of using binds is that the values are automatically escaped producing safer queries. You don’t have to remember to manually escape data...*

El beneficio secundario de usar los "binds" es que los valores se escapan automáticamente y producen consultas más seguras. [No es necesario que escapes manualmente los datos](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#escaping-queries)...

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo enlaces de consultas **(Query Bindings)**, los signos de interrogación en la consulta se reemplazan automáticamente con los valores de la matriz en el segundo parámetro de la función de consulta `query()`.

El beneficio de pasar los parámetros de esta forma es que los valores se escapan automáticamente y producen consultas más seguras.

Puedes hacerlo directamente así

```
$sql = " SELECT DISTINCT c.nombre_campo AS $column
    FROM $schema.campos_basicos AS cb
    INNER JOIN $schema.mapeo_campos_basicos AS mc ON mc.id_campos_basicos = cb.id_campos_basicos
    INNER JOIN $schema.campos AS c ON c.campo_id = mc.campo_id 
    WHERE cb.nombre_campo_destino = 'dato_a_evaluar';"

$query = $this->db->query($sql)
```

Pero la variable puede llevar un carácter que permita hacer inyección SQL y vulnerar tu sistema.

Es una muy buena práctica de seguridad escapar de sus datos antes de enviarlos a su base de datos.

[Query Bindings - CodeIgniter 4.1.3](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings)